# azure key vault - lag on secret changes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Function with `SqlConnectionStr` setting, the value is taken from Azure Key Vault's secret using following syntax:

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=MyKV;SecretName=SqlConnectionStr)`

In the configuration panel I can see it properly understands it as a "Key vault reference", however, when I updated the `SqlConnectionStr` secret's value in the key vault, I can see the Azure function is still using the old value. It's been 2 hours ago and still nothing. The code that uses the value:

```cs
_log.LogInformation($"opening SQL connection");
var cstr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionStr", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cstr);
...
```

Meanwhile I tried restarting the Azure Function several times but that didn't help. This is on production env, I did the same on test a few days ago and experienced the same behavior, after some time (hours) the new value was finally being used by the function.

Is it something that I'm doing wrong? Is it normal behavior? Am I misusing Azure Key Vault with my scenario?

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes time to rotate as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#rotation):

> If the secret version isn't specified in the reference, the app uses the latest version that exists in the key vault. When newer versions become available, such as with a rotation event, the app automatically updates and begins using the latest version within 24 hours. The delay is because App Service caches the values of the key vault references and refetches it every 24 hours. Any configuration change to the app causes an app restart and an immediate refetch of all referenced secrets.

You can also force it to use a particular version of your secret by adding the `SecretVersion` in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of posting this answer, forcing restart the web app or save the configuration won't trigger an immediate re-fetch of all referenced secrets.

An alternative way could be
A. Delete and re-create the secret in key vault
or
B. Change the configuration item to de-reference the secret (to a plain string value) and save it. Then reference the secret and save it again.